# html code returns false

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I am attaching rows after the last row (here, title) of a table. Somehow, the assigned html code returns false.

```
<table id="test">
  <tr>
     <td>Title</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
var text = ''; 
var length = 3; 
var data = 'hello'; 

for (i=0; i< length; i++) {
    text += '<tr>' + 
            '<td>' + data + ' ' + i '</td>' + 
            '</tr>; 
} 
alert('text: ' + text);
$('#test tr:last').after(text);
```

Strangely, the alert message returns 'falsefalsefalse'. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Your code has several syntax errors. I would suggest you check the console and fix them first. Once you've done that your code works absolutely fine. Also note that you shouldn't use `alert()` for debugging. Use `console.log` instead

Comment: for (var i=0; i< length; i++)

Comment: Why the downvotes? The code example is clear, OP just has syntax errors

Comment: @elementzero23 That means: zero research effort.

Comment: **Down-vote** just because of the title. ain't gonna bother reading further.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed som quotation marks and a + sign.

Here is a corrected one:

```
var text = ''; 
var length = 3; 
var data = 'hello'; 

for (i=0; i< length; i++) {
    text += '<tr>' + 
            '<td>' + data + ' ' + i + '</td>' + 
            '</tr>'; 
} 
alert('text: ' + text);
$('#test tr:last').after(text);
```

Comment: You still can’t use `length` as a variable in global scope and still need to declare `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="test">
  <tr>
     <td>Title</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    var text = ''; 
    var length = 3; 
    var data = 'hello'; 
    for (i=0; i < length; i++) {
        text += '<tr>' + 
                '<td>' + data + ' ' + i + '</td>' + 
                '</tr>'; 
     }
     console.log('text: ' + text); // better for debugging
     $('#test tr:last').after(text);
</script>
```

See it running here: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/gtdfy84h/

**Note:** Your **HTML** code is not returning false. That statement is wrong in many levels. HTML is a markup language. The code running and returning unexpected things here is your **javascript** code.

**Note2:** Syntax is very important when writing code, syntactically incorrect code is never expected to work well.